# How to diff with two files by JGit without creating repo?

Tags: diff, jgit

When I use JGit to `diff` with two files, I must create a repo first. But in Git, I only need to use command `git diff --no-index 1.txt 2.txt`.

Is there a way to use `diff` in JGit without creating repo?

Comment: in other words :
How do I do the equivalent of “git diff --no-index file1 file2” with jgit?
when using “git diff --no-index file1 file2”, it doesn't need a git repository

Answer (score 4):

thank you! I have solved this question!

### method is below

```
private static String getDiff(String file1, String file2) {
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        RawText rt1 = new RawText(new File(file1));
        RawText rt2 = new RawText(new File(file2));
        EditList diffList = new EditList();
        diffList.addAll(differ.diff(COMP, rt1, rt2));
        new DiffFormatter(out).format(diffList, rt1, rt2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

---

thank you for your help!

Comment: And what is `differ` in this snippet?

Comment: `new HistogramDiff().diff(RawTextComparator.DEFAULT, rt1, rt2)` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Hm I don't understand the question exactly, but maybe you are looking for something like gitective which makes it with the help of his `BlobUtils` "[Diff two files](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective#diff-two-files)" to a more easy task.

Comment: means : 
How do I do the equivalent of “git diff --no-index file1 file2” with jgit?