# How to use JGit to view modifications in the local workspace?

Tags: java, jgit

I can use JGit to view differences between different commits or different branches, but I don't know how to compare uncommitted files with HEAD.
I have searched through the JGit Cookbook, but I still haven't found a solution.

Comment: I don't know anything about JGit, but from a quick search this looks like it's more difficult than it probably ought to be. I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325613/equivalent-of-git-diff-in-jgit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987364/how-to-diff-with-two-files-by-jgit-without-creating-repo) which might be useful (the second one might work even if the files aren't tracked, assuming it's not outdated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, the 'local workspace' is called the working directory. The abstraction to compare files from different sources (working directory, index, commit) in JGit are *tree iterators*.

Once you created two such iterators, you can diff them. To compare the working directory with the HEAD commit, use something like this:

```java
// Create the HEAD tree iterator
ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
ObjectId headTree = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD^{tree}" );
oldTreeIter.reset( reader, headTree );
// Create the working tree iterator
AbstractTreeIterator newTreeIter = new FileTreeIterator(git.getRepository());

// Either: call the diff command
git.diff()
  .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
  .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
  .call();
// Or: use the DiffFormatter to list changes
try (DiffFormatter formatter = new DiffFormatter(NullOutputStream.INSTANCE)) {
  formatter.setRepository(git.getRepository());
  List<DiffEntry> entries = formatter.scan(oldTreeIterator, newTreeIterator);
}
```

JGit's `DiffCommand` just prints the differences to stdout.
Alternatively, `DiffFormatter::scan` may be used to return `DiffEntry`s each describing a change to a file.

For more on JGit's diff API you may want to read this article, I've written long ago: https://www.codeaffine.com/2016/06/16/jgit-diff/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I can use formatter.format(oldTreeIterator, newTreeIterator) to see the modified content.

Comment: FYI, I now added snippets for the different types of diffing to the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/), see [List changed files between two commits](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/DiffFilesInCommit.java)
 [List changed files in index](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/DiffIndexChanges.java)
 [List changed files in checkout](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/DiffLocalChanges.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Git git = Git.open(new File("xxx"));
    Repository repository = git.getRepository();
    DiffFormatter diffFormatter = new DiffFormatter(System.out);
    diffFormatter.setRepository(repository);

    ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
    CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
    ObjectId headTree = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD^{tree}" );
    oldTreeIter.reset( reader, headTree );
    AbstractTreeIterator newTreeIter = new FileTreeIterator(git.getRepository());
    diffFormatter.format(oldTreeIter, newTreeIter);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).